# How to get name respect to that id form mysql table?

Tags: mysql, django

In my project i have crud like operation, so when i select department i save id of that  item , and bind to table to show that inserted records , so when i bind department i want to bind name of that department not that id . pls help me in this..

Model.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
  ACTIVE = 1
  INACTIVE = 2
  DELETED = 3
  STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (ACTIVE, 'active'),
    (INACTIVE, 'inactive'),
    (DELETED, 'deleted'),
  )
  department_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  department_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,  null=False)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
  modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

 objects = UserManager()

  class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = "ht_department"

  def __str__(self):
    return self.department_id
```

forms.py

```
class EmpForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Employee
      fields = ["employee_id", "Name", "designation", "department_id", "manager_id", 
       "date_of_joining","date_of_birth", "location_id", "email", "contact_number",                  
         "password", "created_by", "modified_by", "status",   "user_type"]



class dept(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Department
      fields = ["department_id", "department_name", "created_by", "modified_by", "status"]


class EmpLoc(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ["location_id", "location_name", "created_by", "modified_by", "status"]
```

html

```
      <tbody id="myTable">
                {% for employee in employees %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ employee.employee_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.designation}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.department_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.manager_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.location_id}}</td>
                    <td>

                        <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                        <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

Here is my updated code for EmployeeModel:

```
Employee Model (Updated)   

   class Employee(models.Model):
     ACTIVE = 1
     INACTIVE = 2
     DELETED = 3
     STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (ACTIVE, 'active'),
    (INACTIVE, 'inactive'),
    (DELETED, 'deleted'),
   )
   USER_TYPE = (
    (1, 'user'),
    (2, 'hr'),
   )
  employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True)
  Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
  designation = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
  department_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
  manager_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
  date_of_joining = models.DateField(null=False)
  date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False)
  location_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True,  
  null=False)
  contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=10 , unique=True,   
  null=False)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
  modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, 
  choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
  user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE)
  objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["Name"]

is_anonymous = "FALSE"
is_authenticated = "TRUE"

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = "ht_employee"
```

Comment: please show the Employee Model.

Comment: have you tried **`{{ employee.department_id.department_name}}`**?

Comment: @JPG i tried your but not worked..

Comment: your model design is wrong. you should look for ForeignKey relation. Create relation in Employee with Department model as ForeignKey

Answer (score 0):

You should update the department_id field in the employee as a foreign key in order to get the name of the department so it will be as:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
     department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
```

and then to get the department name in template

```
{{employee.department.department_name}}
```